# Does MySQL table row contain two values

Tags: mysql

I have a table with two columns:

```
ID1 | ID2
---------
 1  | A
 3  | V
 1  | C
 4  | B
 5  | Q
 1  | S
```

And I want to be able to find out if any row has, say ID1 = 5 and ID2 = Q , and return a true / false value.

Comment: Please read this tutorial:  

http://www.tizag.com/mysqlTutorial/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Of course

```
SELECT * FROM table where ID1='5' and ID2='Q'
```

PHP <sub>(I am just guessing this backend)</sub>

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM table where ID1='5' and ID2='Q'";
$result = mysql_query($query);
if(mysql_num_rows($result)) { return true; }
else { return false; }
```

Comment: You are downloading all selected data to memory, only to check if there are any results - very inefficient.

Comment: @Tomasz Wysocki, I agree on you solution on terms of performance, but what I tried to do was to guide the OP to solve his problem, not solve his problem by me. Besides, judging by the nature of question, I am guessing OP's is not faily a comfortable programmer in php/mysql so my example is easy to understand and use, since the logic is same as the simplest use of mysql in php.

Answer (score 0):

`1` means `TRUE` for mysql

```
SELECT 1
FROM your_table
WHERE ID1 = 5 AND ID2 = 'Q'
```

Answer (score 0):

for example this?

```
SELECT 1
FROM TABLE
WHERE ID1 = 5 AND ID2 = 'Q'
```

Answer (score 0):

Efficient query for your purpose (faster than other examples):

```
SELECT 1 FROM table where ID1='5' and ID2='Q' LIMIT 1
```

PHP sample:

```
<?php
    $query = "SELECT 1 FROM table where ID1='5' and ID2='Q' LIMIT 1";
    echo bool(mysql_num_row(mysql_query($query)));
?>
```